# Ticking checkbox in google sheet with Google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

[This is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM5wR.png)

i have problem with ticking checkbox in google sheet .
the first i'm using this code google sheet

> =if(countif($A$4:$A$55,E$4)=1,FALSE,TRUE)

for automatic ticking in checkbox .

But on a particular day, I couldn't uncheck the box   .
I don't remove the check mark myself if I don't delete the code.
i try finding google app script for automatic ticking checkbox based on date but not found that .
This is my code of google app script

```
 function checkbox() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 spreadsheet.getRange('C26').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=if(countif($A$4:$A$55,E$4)=1,FALSE,TRUE)');
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('C26:AE26'), 
SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.ALTERNATE_SERIES);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about `But on a particular day, I couldn't uncheck the box . I don't remove the check mark myself if I don't delete the code. i try finding google app script for automatic ticking checkbox based on date but not found that .`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: I think the explanation seems a bit difficult so I made this video for you to watch: https://youtu.be/WnV2xY_3TjA

Comment: try `range.check() and range.uncheck()` you don't need to use formulas at all.

Comment: I am very grateful for your help.